Send SPL token from PDA to ATA
I was testing
https://github.com/ashishpandiit23/tokentopdatransfer/blob/master/programs/ANCHORFIRST/src/lib.rs
but once i try to test sendtokenpda with Solana Play Ground alway i get 
If somebody can explain or test it in Solpg and tell me what should i supposed to do it would really get help to me !

Here's an example using the anchor_spl::token_interface::transfer_checked function to transfer SPL Tokens from a PDA to an ATA.
use anchor_spl::{
    token_interface::{
        TokenAccount, 
        Mint, 
        TokenInterface, 
        TransferChecked, 
        transfer_checked
    }, 
    associated_token::AssociatedToken
}

then:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ExampleContext<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    //Signer
    owner: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = owner
    )]
    //Signer ATA
    owner_ata: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        //Example seeds
        seeds = [b"vault", owner.key().as_ref(), mint.key().as_ref()],
        bump = pda.bump,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = pda
    )]
    //PDA - VAULT
    pda: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    //SPL_TOKEN/TOKEN2022
    mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
    associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>
}

impl<'info> ExampleContext<'info> {

    pub fn send_spl_tokens(
        &mut self,
        amount: u64
    ) -> Result<()> {
        
        //Transfer Checked CPI, This works for SPLS AND TOKEN2022
        let accounts = TransferChecked {
            from: self.pda.to_account_info(),
            to: self.owner_ata.to_account_info(),
            authority: self.pda.to_account_info(),
            mint: self.mint.to_account_info()
        };

        let seeds = &[
            &b"vault"[..],
            &self.owner.key().to_bytes()[..],
            &self.mint.key().to_bytes()[..],
            &[self.pda.bump],
        ];

        let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];

        let ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            self.token_program.to_account_info(),
            accounts,
            signer_seeds
        );

        transfer_checked(ctx, amount, self.mint.decimals)
    }
}

pub fn send_tokens(ctx: Context<ExampleContext>, amount: u64)  ->  Result<()> {
    // Send Tokens
    ctx.accounts.send_spl_tokens(amount)
}

Have a nice day.

thanks for sharing this ! but i really confused to integrate to my app :D i'm newest here. But when i tried to run my own code it's giving
Program logged: "Instruction: Sendtokenpda"
Program logged: "token process start for PDA transfer..."
Program logged: "before: 0"
Program logged: "0 bump after"
Program logged: "The given Account is not mutable"
Program logged: "panicked at 'explicit panic', src/accounts/account.rs:418:13"
Program consumed: 10364 of 199700 compute units
Program returned error: "SBF program panicked"
this messages

|
130 |     bump = pda.bump,
|                ^^^^ unknown field
i get this error

Also if you wanna check some differences b4 0.28.0 and pos you can check this post:
https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/token-2022-in-anchor-program/10397#10397

gist.github.com/belivenn/45aca827e19e40b5cbf1d6c1c05a81a5 if you wanna check just wrote few basic functions, sending tokens from ata to pda, sending from pda to ata then close the ATA.
